# PHP - expresiones regulares para permitir letras , números y un punto

Tags: php

Yo he tratado:

```
    if (preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $string)) {
```

pero solo me permite letras y números y me falta permitir el punto, lo que quiero es que se acepten ip y dns.

Ejemplo:

- google.cl
- 8.8.8.8

Comment: Estaría bien que especificaras el formato exacto (si es que lo necesitas). La respuesta de *dobledom* te da la solucion de añadir puntos. pero aceptaria valores como `"."` o `"8.....8....8"`... etc.

Answer (score 2):

Basta con añadir un punto `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/"`

Recuerda que siempre puedes probar tus expresiones regulares online de forma sencilla en sitios como [regxr.com](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: para abreviar puedes poner `"/^[\w\d.]+$/i"`. `\w` para letras, `\d` para digitos y la `i` final para que sea indiferente mayusculas o minusculas.